# Cloth collision error with rigid body

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

[image]

What is wrong with animation, when object and cloth falling?

Answer (score 0):

In the CLOTH Object Collisions, you need to set an appropriate "Distance".  You probably have this set too large

Answer (score 0):

I bet that that the center of the object is not inside the object:
on first frame, click with right mouse button and choose "origin to center of mass"

[image]